# Query formula if cell values match W/and statement Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I am trying to query a range but I am not getting the entire range I expect

`=query(test!$A$1:$C, "select * where B<>'person-person' and A='"&E2&"'", 1)`
[image]

I get

[image]

But I expect

[image]

I can not get why the query is not posting back the expected results

A Google Sheet with the test data

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. No need for a helper column

```
=QUERY(test!A1:C,"SELECT * WHERE (B <> 'person-person' and C is not null) or (C is null)")
```